# Unable to import users in RTC with LDAP configuration

Tags: rtc, opendj

I have configured RTC with LDAP OpenDJ.
Now I am trying to import users but it is not giving any user list after search with * i.e. for all users.
However I am able to login to RTC using LDAP user itself.
I have given below filters in WAS LDAP user registry settings:

User filter: `(&(uid=%v)(objectclass=inetOrgPerson))` 
Group filter:`(&(cn=%v)(|(objectclass=groupOfNames)`(objectclass=posixGroup))) 
User ID map: *:cn 
Group ID map: *:cn 
Group member ID map:
`ibm-allGroups:member;ibm-allGroups:uniqueMember 
With Base DN cn=JazzGroups,sc=ibm,dc=rtc,dc=com`

Mapping in `ccm_war,jts_war and rm_war` is done, 
I am able to map groups, users.

Is there any problem with OpenDJ?
Please help out in importing users.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry I have no experience with RTC (not even sure what it stands out for) but OpenDJ is fully compliant with LDAPv3 and thus should work nicely with any client that has proper support of LDAP.
You might not be able to import users due to missing schema, lack of permissions for the user, or trying to add users with an already hashed password...

Please check OpenDJ access logs for details of failures. Usually the message in case of an error is pretty explicit.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to import users now :-
I corrected few advanced properties Base DN, find user, etc in RTC admin GUI.
BTW thanks for your comment Ludovic Poitou.